# Multiple ifs javascript, don't working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why nothing happens? I would like to make a script giving the highest value from 3 variables.

```
var a = parseInt(prompt("Variable giving", ""));
var b = parseInt(prompt("Variable giving", ""));
var c = parseInt(prompt("Variable giving", ""));
var m = 2;
var m = a;

if (b > m)
{
  m = b;
}

if (c > m)
{
  m = c;
}

if (d > m)
{
  m = d;
}

if (a != c || a != b || b != c)
{
  document.write(m);
}
else
{
  document.write("One of variables is as same as another one");
}
```

Comment: you're overwriting m: `var m=2;  var m=a;`

Comment: @Data That's fine I believe...

Comment: Yes, i am just want to variable will be treated like a integer type.

Comment: I don't think `d` is defined. Did you look at your console to see if any errors pop up?

Comment: "Nothing" rarely happens. Check in the browser console for error messages.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I didn't even know about error console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **an error** in your code. There's no `d` variable that makes your script stop working.

Use simple condition like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a=parseInt(prompt("Variable giving",""));
  var b=parseInt(prompt("Variable giving",""));
  var c=parseInt(prompt("Variable giving",""));
  var m=a;
  if (a > b && a > c)
    m = a + " is highest.";
  else if (b > c)
    m = b + " is highest.";
  else
    m = c + " is highest.";
  document.write(m);
</script>
```

Comment: Or, y'know, `Math.max(a, b, c)`. But telling OP what to do doesn't actually answer their question, which is why their code doesn't work.

Comment: @Jordan Found the answer. He he.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to do this:

```
document.write(Math.max(a,b,c));
```

Comment: Or, y'know, `Math.max(a, b, c)`. But telling OP what to do doesn't actually answer their question, which is why their code doesn't work.